# Printing a Singly Linked List

Tags: c

I have a problem with this function.  When I call it, the clients should be printed from the last (tail), to the first (head).

The problem is that I want to print them from the first (head) to the last (tail).  Everything that I have tried has either resulted in a segmentation fault or prints only the first client.

Note that the program is about a bank.  I have a queue of customers that I want to print in order.

Thank you in advance!

```
void printAll(clientData* tail) {
    clientData *current;
    current = tail;
    if (current == NULL) {
        printf("There is no client in queue\n");
        return ;
    }
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%s %s %d/%d/%d %s %s %s %s\n",
            current->firstname,
            current->lastname,
            current->birthday.day,
            current->birthday.month,
            current->birthday.year,
            current->bankaccount,
            current->telephone,
            current->email,
            current->bankcommand);

        current = current->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Erm ... You have a (singly) linked-list. You're currently starting at the head (the first node) and traversing it.

Comment: This question should be improved. At least, you should describe your date type `clientData` and how the list is created

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a stack. Your system provides one automatically for you when you call a function recursively:

```
void printAll(clientData* current)
{
    if (current->next != NULL) {
        printAll(current->next);
    }
    printf("%s %s %d/%d/%d %s %s %s %s\n", current->firstname,current->lastname,current->birthday.day,current->birthday.month,current->birthday.year,current->bankaccount,current->telephone,current->email,current->bankcommand);
}
```

Comment: In that case, the only explanation I can see is that current->next is NULL for the tail end of your list. Try removing the if (just call `printAll(current->next);` regardless), and see if you get a segfault.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with how your `next` pointers are set up. Check the code where you build the list, or post it here so we can take a look.

Comment: here it is:

    if(head==NULL){


         head=customer;
          *tail=customer;
          head->next=NULL;
       }else{
       customer->next=*tail;
       *tail=customer; 
       }

Comment: Well, I can see nothing wrong with that, provided that head and customer are of type `clientData*` and tail is of type `clientData**`. Anyone else want to take a swing at it?

Comment: Please show the data structure clientData and the code where you build the list (including its variable declarations).